# Why Oracle PL/SQL insert into table is not working with cursor?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to insert date into temporary table, but it's not saving any data. How should I change cursor date parameters?

The procedure is running without any error message but output `xx_cdf_output_utl$.log('inside loop');` is not working.

`xx_cdf_output_utl$.log('after loop');` log is printing fine.

Right now added three parameters: `p_date_from (date)`, `p_date_to (date)`, `p_line_type_lookup_code (varchar2)`

```sql
    procedure gather_data(
     -- p_valid_invoices_count out number,
     -- p_invalid_invoices_count out number,
      p_date_from in date,
      p_date_to in date,
      p_line_type_lookup_code in varchar2) is

    ROUTINE constant varchar2(65) := PACKAGE_NAME||'.GATHER_DATA';
      cursor c_inv(   
         p_date_from in date,
         p_date_to in date,
         p_line_type_lookup_code in varchar2) is 
      select
        inv.invoice_id,
        inv.invoice_num,
        inv.invoice_amount,
        inv.invoice_date,
        inv.amount_paid,
        pas.gross_amount,
        pas.payment_num,
        ven.vendor_id,
        ven.vendor_name
      from
        ap_invoices_all inv, -- invoice table
        ap_payment_schedules_all pas, -- payment schedules table
        po_vendors ven -- vendors table
      where
        inv.invoice_date between p_date_from and p_date_to and 
        inv.wfapproval_status in (
          'NOT REQUIRED',
          'WFAPPROVED',
          'MANUALLY APPROVED') and
        pas.amount_remaining != 0 and
        nvl(pas.hold_flag, 'N') != 'Y' and
        (p_line_type_lookup_code is not null and
        exists(
          select
            1 
          from
            ap_invoice_distributions_all ind -- distribution table
          where                                  
            ind.amount != 0 and
            ind.line_type_lookup_code = p_line_type_lookup_code and
            ind.invoice_id = inv.invoice_id) or
            p_line_type_lookup_code is null) and 
            pas.invoice_id = inv.invoice_id and
            ven.vendor_id = inv.vendor_id;

      l_date_from date := nvl(to_date(p_date_from, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
      l_date_to date := nvl(to_date(p_date_to, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), trunc(to_date(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')));
      l_line_type_lookup_code varchar2(240) := p_line_type_lookup_code;
    begin
      for l_inv_rec in c_inv(
        l_date_from,
        l_date_to,
        l_line_type_lookup_code)
      loop
        xx_cdf_output_utl$.log('inside loop');
        insert into xx_zm_invoice_temp(
          invoice_id,
          invoice_num,
          invoice_amount,
          invoice_date,
          amount_paid,
          gross_amount,
          payment_num,
          vendor_id,
          vendor_name)
         -- vendor_amount_total,
         -- vendor_amount_valid_flg)
        values(
          l_inv_rec.invoice_id,
          l_inv_rec.invoice_num,
          l_inv_rec.invoice_amount,
          l_inv_rec.invoice_date,
          l_inv_rec.amount_paid,
          l_inv_rec.gross_amount,
          l_inv_rec.payment_num,
          l_inv_rec.vendor_id,
          l_inv_rec.vendor_name);
      end loop;
    xx_cdf_output_utl$.log('after loop');
    exception
      when xx_cdf_error_utl$.e_internal_exception then
        xx_cdf_error_utl$.raise_error;
      when others then
        xx_cdf_error_utl$.output_unexp_exception(
          p_routine => ROUTINE);
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
  l_date_from date := nvl(to_date(p_date_from, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), to_date('2019-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
  l_date_to date := nvl(to_date(p_date_to, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), trunc(to_date(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD')));
```

the

```
to_date(p_date_to, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

has to convert `p_date` from a date to a string first, and it will use the session NLS parameters to do that. As it isn't erroring I imagine your date format has a 2-digit year, possibly the kind-of-default DD-MON-RR. You are effectively doing something like:

```
to_date(to_char(p_date_to, 'dd-mon-rr'), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

which would translate today's date to 0023-03-20, which isn't what you intended at all. You end up looking for a range of dates in year 0023, or maybe 0020, so it's not surprising you do't find any matching data.

You don't need to convert the parameters to or from strings, you can do:

```
  l_date_from date := nvl(p_date_from, date '2019-01-01');
  l_date_to date := nvl(p_date_to, trunc(sysdate));
```

You can truncate the parameter values if you think that might be necessary, but with a `trunc()` call, not by bouncing through strings.

You don't really need `l_date_from` or `l_date_to` though (or `l_line_type_lookup_code`); you could do the `nvl()` firstly in the cursor call:

```
  for l_inv_rec in c_inv(
    nvl(p_date_from, date '2019-01-01'),
    nvl(p_date_to, trunc(sysdate)),
    p_line_type_lookup_code)
```

Having the same name for the procedure parameters and the cursor parameters might be confusing - though the way you're currently using them, the cursor doesn't really need the parameters - it can refer directly to the procedure values, and use `nvl()` internally:

```
inv.invoice_date between nvl(p_date_from, date '2019-01-01') and nvl(p_date_to, trunc(sysdate)) and
```

I'm always a bit wary of using `between` with dates because it's easy to forget it's inclusive, and you can accidentally pick up the same data - at exactly midnight - in more than one call. It's a bit safer and clearer to use a range:

```
inv.invoice_date >= nvl(p_date_from, date '2019-01-01') and
inv.invoice_date < nvl(p_date_to, trunc(sysdate)) and
```

decided explicitly if the last condition should use `<` or `<=`. The latter is usually what you mean if the table values have non-midnight times.

And you could use an implicit cursor, but that's partly a matter of taste...

You could even give your procedure arguments default values, but you might be restricted in how it's called.